# Trying to remove directory names from application URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

My badluck I'm a UI developer and given the task of URL rewriting please help me.

I've this URL with me `/abc/def/ghi/somefile.php?id=1` 
I want it to just `somefile?id=1`

I do have this code in my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/abc/def/ghi/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

but after uploading the htaccess to server this is giving me 404 error after removing the /abc/def/ghi/ part.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

RewriteRule not receive first slash

RewriteRule ^abc/def/ghi/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]